How does passive with work with both を and は

自分は適切な処置を施されて、

I was given the appropriate treatment.
but why は　and を　are both used together?

Well, firstly, the underlying form here is not about “〜は” but about “〜が”. The underlying form is “自分が適切な処置を施されて。”. This is called the “indirect passive”, sometimes also called the “suffering passive” though that's a terminology many don't like. The passive in Japanese, unlike in English namely need not reduce valency. Namely:

“（私の）パンが食べられた。” [direct passive]
“（私は）パンを食べられた。” [indirect passive]

Both mean “My bread was eaten.” but the latter is generally considered a far more natural way to phrase this concept. Because a piece of bread has no will and no volition. It's generally the subject of the passive that's the thing materially affected by the statement and a piece of bread doesn't care so the upper statement wouldn't be used much to convey this. The passive can be used without reducing valency and still keep it's object in Japanese, which is what is happening in your example.
It can in fact for this reason also be used with intransitive verbs such as:

（私は）お父さんに死なれた。-> “My father died.”

This at first glance confusing construct with “お父さんに” as the agent of an intransitive passive is hard to directly translate. “I was died by my father.” evidently makes no sense in English but this is perfectly fine in Japanese. It expresses that the father died, and the speaker was the one affected by this, feeling the loss. It's called the “suffering passive” for this reason. “（私の）お父さんが死んだ。” is of course also completely fine to say “My father died.” but doesn't carry the same nuance of the speaker personally affected by it and is more of a matter of fact statement.

The example with お父さんに looks like the "adversative / suffering passive".  This is commonly expressed in English with constructions like "My father died on me", emphasizing that "me" was negatively impacted by the main clause.

That "indirect passive voice" construction could probably be alternatively called middle voice (see also e.g. 1, 2).
